# MySQL Join with optional select value

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, where-clause

I have a query on a Left join, where the Table who joins can contain zero rows. The problem is that if I select from that, then there are no rows where the join table contains zero rows.
How can I select it then anyway?

Here is my query

```
SELECT server.id
    , COALESCE( AVG( playerData.player ) , 0 ) AS average 
FROM server 
LEFT JOIN playerData ON server.id = playerData.serverID 
    AND (playerData.timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -10000)
```

The playerData table stores in one row how many people were on a server on a specific time. And multiple rows of this needs to be calculated to an average and this needs to be joined to the other query. When I omit the secound select column it gives me all rows (like it should), otherwise it only shows a result where also appropriate rows in the playerData table exists.

Additional Table data: playerData Table:

[image: playerData table]

For the other table only the id column is important in this case.

Comment: it would be great knowing table structures!

Comment: Your description is not clear. Please consider providing some sample data and the desired output.

Comment: Please note that you are mixing **non-aggregated** and **aggregated** columns in a query **without** `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT server.id
    , COALESCE( AVG( playerData.player ) , 0 ) AS average 
FROM server 
LEFT JOIN playerData ON server.id = playerData.serverID 
    AND (playerData.timestamp > UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) -10000)
group by server.id
```

Your query is missing the `group by` clause.  When you include an aggregation function (like `AVG()`), the query automatically becomes an aggregation query.  Without `group by`, all rows are aggregated into a single row.  Presumably, you want one row per `server.id`.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. (But I try to add additional Information to my Question anyways as suggested in the comments, for people who have the same problem)

Comment: It make sense now. If I use aggregate function in sub-query will it still consider aggregation query for outer one?